# 100 items 100 baskets divisor association analysis problem

Tags: data-mining, market-basket-analysis

I have the following exercise question:

> Suppose there are 100 items, numbered 1 to 100, and also 100 baskets, also numbered 1 to 100. Item i is in basket b if and only if i divides b with no remainder. Thus, item 1 is in all the baskets, item 2 is in all fifty of the even-numbered baskets, etc. for example Basket 12 consists of items {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12}

Given this, I'm trying to solve the following 3 questions:

> (a) If the support threshold is 5, which items are frequent?
>
> (b) what is the confidence of the following association rules?
>
> (1) {5, 7} → 2.
>
> (2) {2, 3, 4}→ 5.

which way I should be approaching these types of questions?

Comment: Isn't this best suited for [Mathematics SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/) or maybe [Cross-validated SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) ? I fail to see how this is related to Data Science, this is rather related to pure probability/set math and how it fit data-mining itself. Note: Although this is an important concept for the tags referred this is not applied but rather pure math.

Answer (score 2):

**a)** The items that are frequent are $\{1,2,3,4,5,\dots,20\}$ because these all appear in at least 5 baskets.

**b)**

**(1)** $\{5, 7\} → 2$. Then $Confidence=\frac{1}{2}$

hence 5 and 7 will appear together in basket no. 35 and 70 and 2 will appear along with 7 and 5 in basket no. 70 so:

$$ Confidence = \frac{support(\{5,7\}\cup\{2\})}{support(\{5,7\})}= \frac{1}{2} $$

**(2)** $\{2, 3, 4\}→ 5$. Then $Confidence=\frac{1}{8} $

$\{2,3,4\}$ appear in baskets having basket number multiple of 12 ($LCM\{2,3,4\}$) i.e in basket no $\{12,24,...,60,.....,96\}$ and $\{2,3,4,5\}$ appear together only in basket no 60.

$→ Confidence=\frac{1}{8}$